# When launching a kernel with cooperative threads, and it reduces the number of blocks per grid, how do I make that an error instead of a warning?

Tags: cupy

This is for a [CuPy kernel](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.RawKernel.html#cupy.RawKernel). I get the following warning when I try to launch it.

```
UserWarning: The grid size will be reduced from 48 to 24, as the specified grid size exceeds the limit.
```

I am doing some extreme performance optimizations and hardcoding the relevant constants for my program, amongst them `blocks_per_grid`. An unexpected reduction in the number of blocks launched will make my program incorrect, so I'd rather it errors out instead. How can I do that?